# Sketch the polar graphs

Tags: polar-coordinates

Any advice on how to sketch polar graphs? 
I have tried transforming to rectangular coordinates, but its not really much help
$$
r=1+\sin(\theta) \\
r^2=4\cos(2\theta)
$$
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: any how can you tell the curve is gonna look like that just by looking at the expresssion? thats the real question as im not allowed to use any digital stuff/graphing calcs :O

Comment: Do you know what _polar graph paper_ is? (This is not meant to be sarcastic. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to sketch polar graphs is to plug in "nice" values of $\theta$ (e.g.,$ \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2},$ etc.) and plot the points you get to see if you can see the curve.

Plotting these points gives you the rough idea that the graph of the first one is a cardioid. (You can do it yourself or look at about page 6 of http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Precalculus/Section_8.2-Graphs%20of%20Polar%20Equations/Graphs%20of%20Polar%20Equations.pdf)

You can do the same for the other equation to see that its graph is that of a lemniscate (although for this one you may have to choose your points wisely, because the domain is restricted).

Another method is also to recognize that certain equations correspond to certain graphs.